What is the pdf of the sample mean of a distribution
So I'm struggling with what I feel like should be a simple passage in a statistical inference book.

Given an iid sample ($X_1, ..., X_n)$ and a sample mean $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}(X_1+...+X_n)$, if $f(y)$ is the pdf of $Y = (X_1+...+X_n)$, then $f_\bar{X}(x) = nf(nx)$ is the pdf of $\bar{X}$.

The thing I think I'm stumped by is the first $n$ in $nf(nx)$. I'm trying to think through a trivial case where our distribution for $X_i$ is that $x_i=1$ with probability $1$. So if we take a sample of $n = 3$ we would have $f(3) = P(y = 3) = P(1+1+1 = 3) = 1$, which seems right. From there I look at $f_\bar{X}(1) = 3f(3*1) = 3*1 = 3$ which obviously doesn't work, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Your formula is for r.v's with densities. Not valid for discrete r.v.'s. $f_{\overline x}$ is meant to be a density, not a probability mass function.

If you are given a result involving PDF it is presuming that distribution is continuous, so why are you validating it with a discrete case? Or is your book not distinguishing between PMF and PDF?

@geetha290krm, I see. In most cases so far I think the book's been a bit more explicit when it handled results that only applied in the discrete or continuous case, but I feel silly to have missed it, thanks!
